# manytoone doctrine in symfony2

Tags: exception, symfony, doctrine

I have users and groups related manytoone, and then deleting group which is used in users I`m getting:

> DBALException: An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM
>   Groups WHERE id = ?' with params...   Integrity constraint violation:
>   1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint
>   fails...
>
> DBALException: An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM
>   Groups WHERE id = ?' with params...  Integrity constraint violation:
>   1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint
>   fails

...
and it is normal, how i can catch exception, or check if it is used somehow?

Answer (score 0):

This means that you probably have your database set up with foreign keys, like this:

```
|---------|
| User    |
|---------|
| id      |
| groupId |
|---------|

|-------|
| Group |
|-------|
| id    |
|-------|
```

Where `User.groupId` refers to `Group.id`. This means that when you delete a Group, you need to define what the database should do about Users that are part of that Group.

Depending on your intent, can change your foreign key constraint to handle this situation. You didn't mention what database type you're using, but I know that in MySQL you can have a `CONSTRAINT` with an `ON DELETE` clause, and give it the options of `RESTRICT` (default, what you're seeing now), `CASCADE` (delete all the Users associated with that Group), and `SET NULL` (set `groupId` to `NULL` for Users whose Group was deleted).

Answer (score 0):

Besides using the `ON DELETE` clause at the database level (which is clearly the elegant and framework independent way) you may want to check for existing users of the group directly in your code. In this case, you could execute another query.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

// Set your group id as the desired criterion
$criteria = array('GroupId' => $group->getId);

// Get all users that match the criterion
$users = $em->getRepository("YourBundle:User")->findBy($criteria);

// Check whether the returned array is empty
if(count($users) != 0){
    // Do your exception handling
}else {
    // Do regular operations, like deleting the group
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all the users inside the group when you delete the group , you can tell doctrine to cascade the delete . So the oneToMany section of your metadata file (say groups.orm.yml) will look something like

```
oneToMany:
    users:
        targetEntity: Users
        mappedBy: user
        cascade: [remove]
```

More info here http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations